# $Recycle.Bin folders inquiry

Tags: hard-drive

I've got one such folder on each drive. But on some drives it's named as "$Recycle.Bin" and on others it's "$RECYCLE.BIN" all capital letters. Is there any difference between these folders due to different names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between these two folders. Both are same.

Thanks